Cross-lagged panel analysis many variables
I'm planning an analysis to look at individual coping strategies, specifically what predicts well-being at follow-up (or vice versa). I think cross-lagged panel analysis might be the best approach so we can say something about the direction of effects. Below is a model that I'm considering but I'm unsure about a couple of things:
Are these too many variables for a cross-lagged panel analysis? (We have a sample size of around 600)
Would I need paths between all the coping strategies too? (I think that might get very complicated).
I'd be super grateful if anyone has any advice on the best way to approach this!


One way to find out whether your sample is large enough would be to simulate the path model with the expected effects using Monte Carlo simulation techniques. That way, you could find out whether the path coefficients and their standard errors can be estimated without bias and whether you have sufficient statistical power to detect the effects of interest.
The autoregressive paths between all variables will probably have to be included in the model since these tend to be substantial (at least non-zero). Whether you need all the cross-lagged paths between the coping strategies (or which ones are needed) is difficult to answer. This is a theoretical and/or empirical question.,
